# How to use vis.js with map

Tags: visualization, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to build a network visualization with vis.js and display it on a map (similar to Geo-layout in Gephi). Do you happen to know if something already exists to achieve such goal? (I don't even need to use vis.js if you have suggestions)

So far I tried/thought of using mapbox but I abandoned the idea of a real map because it it turning out to be fairly complex.

I downgraded expectation to doing the following:

- done: have an image of a map in the background and have some big nodes that I can position manually by tweaking the x and y position

I still need to do the following:

- Make the small nodes automatically fall into place as if it was a forced layout.

The problem is that I need to disable physics if i need to manually set some positions... this of course stops the smaller nodes from being automatically positioned.

any hints on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have to admit, your question (your requirements) are difficult to understand: I can understand that you need a background image of a map which you already have; but what is Geo-layout of Gephi? What does "automatically fall into place" mean? What place? (add some snippets/screenshots/...) Anyway, if your answer is satisfactory to you, don't forget to accept it so that we can understand whether the question is still of interest or not. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended doing the following, in options set the layout and physics. (for some reason, improved layout has to be false, it was a lucky guess)

```
layout: {  improvedLayout: false }
```

`physics: { enabled: true}`

For the node, set a property called fixed:

```
fixed: { x: true , y: true }
```

Here is the son of the node:

```
{id: 1,  value: 2,  label: 'xx' , x: 320, y:170 ,  fixed: { x: true , y: true } }
```